# How to send Ether Using Web3 and Gas Charges are Paid from Another Address?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I know using this for send Ether (web3):

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: 'Address A',
    to: 'Address B',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
.then(function(receipt){
    ...
});
```

I'm trying to send ether from address A to address B, then the gas fee is paid by address C for the transaction. Does anyone know about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Bitcoin's raw transaction you create payload with `listunspent`, you can't do this for ether in Ethereum.

However you can do this for tokens. Ex: ERC20 Token, you can have address A to `approve` address C to spend his/her ERC20 on their behalf. Once the `approve` transaction has completed, address C can bear the gas for transferring ERC20 token from address A to address B.

Comment: yes it's true I've used a smart contract for something like this (before). But is there any live web3? I'm still learning some of these things